# Unable to find storyboard after rename

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

in an iphone Application I have created a storyboard named **HomeStoryboard.storyboard**, and I get reference to it using:

```
UIStroyboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"HomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

This is working correctly.

However I wanted to change it's name, so I renamed the file to **HomeStoryboard-iPhone.storyboard**

Now when I try to call

```
UIStroyboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"HomeStoryboard-iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

I get an error:

```
'Could not find a storyboard named 'HomeStoryboard-iPhone' in bundle NSBundle ....
```

It seems like renaming the file is not enough. 
What can I do to rename a storyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Does HomeStoryboard-iPhone.storyboard appear in the Copy Bundle Ressources?

Comment: Did U check with the build Phases after edit ..?

Comment: Hope this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694742/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-mainstoryboard-in-bundle-nsbundle

Comment: check Info.plist file name for stroyboard

Comment: Try to reset your Simulator and then clean your App Build Folder
I guess it should work.

Comment: @Arun I did that and additional removed the reference from the project and re-added them and it worked. Thanks. you can put that information as an answer so I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset your Simulator and then clean your App Build Folder.