# could not find a storyboard in xcode5 for ios 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just created a new iPhone app project in Xcode 5, and set the iOS Deployment Target to 5.0. I tried to run the app in the iOS 5.1 simulator, but I got the following error:

```
Could not find a storyboard named ‘Main’ in bundle NSBundle
```

Comment: check the name of the storyboard in .plist and change it accordingly if you are instantiating storyboard.

Comment: @suhit it is same as SB name. still i got error

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694742/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-mainstoryboard-in-bundle-nsbundle

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240054/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-main-in-bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Main.storyboard and Make the following changes to Localization section in File Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project have you choosed (empty, single view)?
Can you see Main.storyboard file in your project resources?
Make sure that in your target (General tab) under Deployment Info section you have selected 'Main' in Main Interface field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
open the info.plist of your project and remove the selected row displayed in screenshot

[image]

Comment: after this one i got same error. use my answer it will help you and fix the bug