# Programmatically load ViewController from Storyboard in app with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, ios10

I am working on an application that is transitioning to having multiple storyboards for different sections of the app. They are linked together by programmatically loading them at the appropriate times.

In a function for when a UIButton is tapped, it should programmatically load a storyboard. The code is like so:

```
- (void)loginTapped:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home.storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeStoryboard"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The storyboard is named the name listed in in the function:

[image: storyboard file name]

and is listed as a target in the project settings appropriately:

[image: storyboard target image]

and has the appropriate ID like so:

[image: storyboard id image]

However, even after setting all this I get the error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Home.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle`

I have tried to follow the advice from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694742/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-mainstoryboard-in-bundle-nsbundle), but nothing has worked. How do I get this storyboard to load?

Comment: Can you try removing the `.storyboard` in the name of the storyboard? So just `storyboardWithName:@"Home"`

Comment: Try with @"Home" and let the method figure out the file extension.

Comment: @nathan, Phillip that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution (as mentioned in the comments above) is to not include the `.storyboard` when providing the name of the storyboard.

**Old**

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home.storyboard" bundle:nil];
```

**New**

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

***To call any ViewController programmatically in ios using Objective c:***

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:Home bundle:nil];

yourDestinationViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@homeStoryboard]; 

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completed:^{}];
```

**yourDestinationViewController** in the code is your view controller.h file.

You want to *import* that viewcontroller.h file in your program, where you want to call the View controller programmatically.

and to create the *property* like below,

```
#import "viewcontroller.h"

@property viewController *yourDestinationViewController;
```